# Why doesn't Javascript add height with the ex unit?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted JavaScript to add height to the current height in css and it works with the px unit but doesn't with the ex unit. Anybody who knows a solution to this?

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
      Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
   width:150px;
   height:100px;
   float:left;
   background:red;
}

.child {
    line-height:2.5ex;
    max-height:5ex;
    margin:2.5ex;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var child = $(".child");

  var height = parseInt(child.css("max-height").split("ex")[0]);

  height = height + 10 ;

  child.css({"max-height": height});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add `ex` when you set the CSS property. From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

> If no explicit unit was specified (like 'em' or '%') then "px" is concatenated to the value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var child = $(".child");

  var height = parseInt(child.css("max-height").split("ex")[0]);

  height = height + 10 ;

  child.css({"max-height": height + "ex"});

});
```

```css
.parent {
   width:150px;
   height:100px;
   float:left;
   background:red;
}

.child {
    line-height:2.5ex;
    max-height:5ex;
    margin:2.5ex;
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
      Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok do I have to do this for every other unit except for px unit?

Comment: Exactly! Added a mention about this in my answer.

Comment: Oh ok thank you ^^ I'm a complete noob in JS and I thought .split("ex") would specify the unit ~

Comment: You're welcome! Basically, you read something like `15ex` from CSS, split it into `15` and `ex`, take only `15`, add `10` to get `25`, and then you have to re-add `ex` to get `15ex`!

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this: `child.css({"max-height": height + 'ex'});`